# Update from 20.04 to 22.10 - Xorg crashing , suspected displaylink driver issue

Tags: drivers, gnome, xorg, 22.10, displaylink

I did a stupid last night and updated my laptop very late at night so all of this is on me. I updated ubuntu and restarted only to find Xserver unable to start. It claims this is due to a segmentation error in the log, but in the trace on screen it says "evdi" (display link). Now I know these displaylink drivers don't have the greatest of reputations and have caused me a bit of pain in the past, so I ran "displaylink-installer uninstall" and the system booted right up with Xserver. **Perfect**.

I do however need to use my external monitors at some point in the future.

startx print screen trace:

```
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux desktop Name 5.19.0-26-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov 23 20:44:15 UTC 2022 x86_64
[...]
xorg-server 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/desktopUser/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Dec  9 16:51:46 2022
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)
MESA-LOADER: failed to open evdi: /usr/lib/dri/evdi_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load driver: evdi
kmsro: driver missing
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x13d) [0x55d66aa7bbdd]
(EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__sigaction+0x50) [0x7f30b5c3bcf0]
(EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
(EE) 2: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (?+0x0) [0x7f30b635524d]
(EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (_dl_catch_exception+0x7a) [0x7f30b5d6d79a]
(EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (_dl_catch_error+0x33) [0x7f30b5d6d853]
(EE) 5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (dlerror+0x29f) [0x7f30b5c8b93f]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (dlclose+0x36) [0x7f30b5c8b696]
(EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (nouveau_drm_screen_create+0x1d6c88) [0x7f30b4159ad8]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (nouveau_drm_screen_create+0x1d6143) [0x7f30b4158f93]
(EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (?+0x0) [0x7f30b36aca36]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (__driDriverGetExtensions_d3d12+0x668ddb) [0x7f30b3d159fb]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (__driDriverGetExtensions_d3d12+0x668d2c) [0x7f30b3d1594c]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (__driDriverGetExtensions_d3d12+0x1c10) [0x7f30b36ae830]
(EE) 13: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (__driDriverGetExtensions_d3d12+0xa3b5) [0x7f30b36b6fd5]
(EE) 14: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (gbm_format_get_name+0x1a66) [0x7f30b5489df6]
(EE) 15: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (gbm_format_get_name+0x1b50) [0x7f30b5489ee0]
(EE) 16: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (gbm_format_get_name+0x1e28) [0x7f30b548a1b8]
(EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
(EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (?+0x0) [0x7f30b54879c0]
(EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
(EE) 18: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (?+0x0) [0x7f30b5487b54]
(EE) 19: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (gbm_create_device+0x4f) [0x7f30b5487c9f]
(EE) 20: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (glamor_egl_init+0x65) [0x7f30b549ed15]
(EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
(EE) 21: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f30b54d97f3]
(EE) 22: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitOutput+0xb8b) [0x55d66a948a7b]
(EE) 23: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x1ce) [0x55d66a908d2e]
(EE) 24: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_init_first+0x90) [0x7f30b5c23510]
(EE) 25: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0x89) [0x7f30b5c235c9]
(EE) 26: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x25) [0x55d66a8f2045]
(EE) 
(EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x337
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/desktopUser/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

Last bit of Xorg.0.log:

```
[  2144.254] (==) modeset(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  2144.254] (==) modeset(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[  2144.254] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  2144.254] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  2144.254] (II) Module "fb" already built-in
[  2144.254] (==) modeset(G0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[  2144.254] (==) modeset(G0): RGB weight 888
[  2144.254] (==) modeset(G0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  2144.254] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[  2144.254] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[  2144.254] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[  2144.254] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2144.254]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.0.1
[  2144.254]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  2144.258] (EE) 
[  2144.258] (EE) Backtrace:
[  2144.258] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x13d) [0x55bb5d4e1bdd]
[  2144.258] (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__sigaction+0x50) [0x7fa11ea3bcf0]
[  2144.258] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[  2144.258] (EE) 2: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (?+0x0) [0x7fa11f19c24d]
[  2144.258] (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (_dl_catch_exception+0x7a) [0x7fa11eb6d79a]
[  2144.259] (EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (_dl_catch_error+0x33) [0x7fa11eb6d853]
[  2144.259] (EE) 5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (dlerror+0x29f) [0x7fa11ea8b93f]
[  2144.259] (EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (dlclose+0x36) [0x7fa11ea8b696]
[  2144.259] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (nouveau_drm_screen_create+0x1d6c88) [0x7fa11cf59ad8]
[  2144.259] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (nouveau_drm_screen_create+0x1d6143) [0x7fa11cf58f93]
[  2144.259] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[  2144.260] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (?+0x0) [0x7fa11c4aca36]
[  2144.260] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (__driDriverGetExtensions_d3d12+0x668ddb) [0x7fa11cb159fb]
[  2144.260] (EE) 11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (__driDriverGetExtensions_d3d12+0x668d2c) [0x7fa11cb1594c]
[  2144.260] (EE) 12: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (__driDriverGetExtensions_d3d12+0x1c10) [0x7fa11c4ae830]
[  2144.260] (EE) 13: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (__driDriverGetExtensions_d3d12+0xa3b5) [0x7fa11c4b6fd5]
[  2144.260] (EE) 14: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (gbm_format_get_name+0x1a66) [0x7fa11e2cfdf6]
[  2144.260] (EE) 15: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (gbm_format_get_name+0x1b50) [0x7fa11e2cfee0]
[  2144.260] (EE) 16: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (gbm_format_get_name+0x1e28) [0x7fa11e2d01b8]
[  2144.260] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[  2144.260] (EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (?+0x0) [0x7fa11e2cd9c0]
[  2144.261] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[  2144.261] (EE) 18: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (?+0x0) [0x7fa11e2cdb54]
[  2144.261] (EE) 19: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (gbm_create_device+0x4f) [0x7fa11e2cdc9f]
[  2144.261] (EE) 20: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (glamor_egl_init+0x65) [0x7fa11e2e4d15]
[  2144.261] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[  2144.261] (EE) 21: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7fa11e31f7f3]
[  2144.261] (EE) 22: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitOutput+0xb8b) [0x55bb5d3aea7b]
[  2144.261] (EE) 23: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x1ce) [0x55bb5d36ed2e]
[  2144.261] (EE) 24: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_init_first+0x90) [0x7fa11ea23510]
[  2144.262] (EE) 25: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0x89) [0x7fa11ea235c9]
[  2144.262] (EE) 26: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x25) [0x55bb5d358045]
[  2144.262] (EE) 
[  2144.262] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x337
[  2144.262] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  2144.262] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[  2144.262] (EE) 
[  2144.262] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
```

I assume the second trace is a bit of a red-herring on account of when uninstalling evdi it beings to work again. Does anyone know of any fixes to make the displaylink drivers work with Ubuntu 22?

Thanks in advance, happy to answer questions and will update with the solution for others if I find it in the mean time.

Ubuntu Version : 22.10

Display Link : displaylink-driver-5.6.1-59.184

Answer (score 0):

Since the last update of my 22.04 LTS system last we I'm encountering a similar problem.

After the update I couldn't login anymore, because of the same xorg crash. I realized that the displaylink driver could be the culprit, because I solved the problem by installing a generic 6.2 kernel and I could then access my system.

Clearly on the fresh kernel there is no displaylink support available. I then tried the procedure suggested here: https://code.berrydejager.com/Fix-DisplayLink_drivers-linux-kernel-6/ . The driver installed without problems, but then again same problem, xorg was crashing at the login. Purged evdi and the display-link driver solved the problem.

I then purged the display-link driver from my older 5.19 kernel that wasn't working anymore, and as before, xorg is now booting without problem also on the older kernel.

Not sure if the problem it comes from the driver itself or from the evdi module (can't access the history of the version in synaptic, so is difficult to know if it was updated lately)